# gpg encrypted files are not listed in the directory

Tags: vb.net, process, gnupg

I have a Windows Service written in VB.net , this service will read some XML files and create gpg encrypted files. The following is the code for doing it

```
 Dim OutputFileWithPath As String = outputFolder + "\" + xmlFile.Name + ".gpg"

                            Dim gpgExecutable As String = getAppSetting("GnuPGLocation") + "gpg"
                            Dim gpgOptions As String = " --recipient " +
                                getAppSetting("Recipient") + " --output """ +
                                OutputFileWithPath + """" + " --encrypt """ +
                                inputFolder + "\" + xmlFile.Name + """"
                           

                            Dim pInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(gpgExecutable, gpgOptions)
                            pInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
                            pInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                            pInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                            _processObject = Process.Start(pInfo)
                            _processObject.WaitForExit()
```

After the program execution , when I try seeing the output folder, i am unable to see anything. But when I run the same command it is asking the file already exists do you want to override. When I execute the same code as Console Application, it works fine. But when I run it as Windows service , I am facing this problem. But the same command works on D: drive as the output folder. Will there be any problem with the permissions to the folder?

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `outputFolder` is what you want? Does the user account that the service is run under have write permission in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the user account which is used for running the WindowsService, if we run it using the user id which is configured with the private key and public key, it is working.